# is there a way to run a job at a set time later, without cron, say a scheduled queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, queue, scheduled-tasks, background-process

I have a rails application where I want to run a job in the background, but I need to run the job 2 hours from the original event.

The use case might be something like this:

User posts a product listing.
Background job is queued to syndicate listing to 3rd party api's, but even after original request, the response could take a while and the 3rd party's solution is to poll them every 2 hours to see if we can get a success acknowledgement.

So is there a way to queue a job, so that a worker daemon knows to ignore it or only listen to it at the scheduled time?

I don't want to use cron because it will load up a whole application stack and may be executed twice on overlapping long running jobs.

Can a priority queue be used for this?  What solutions are there to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try delayed job - https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

something along these lines?

```
class ProductCheckSyndicateResponseJob < Struct.new(:product_id)
  def perform
    product = Product.find(product_id)

    if product.still_needs_syndicate_response
      # do it ...

      # still no response, check again in two hours
      Delayed::Job.enqueue(ProductCheckSyndicateResponseJob.new(product.id), :run_at => 2.hours.from_now)
    else
      # nothing to do ...
    end
  end
end
```

initialize job first time in controller or maybe before_create callback on model?

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(ProductCheckSyndicateResponseJob.new(@product.id), :run_at => 2.hours.from_now)
```

Comment: I had heard about delayed job but I thought they always executed immediately.  I didn't know about the :run_at

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Rufus Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) gem. It runs as a background thread, so you don't have to load the entire application stack again. Add it to your Gemfile, and then your code is as simple as:

```
# in an initializer,
SCHEDULER = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

# then wherever you want in your Rails app,
SCHEDULER.in('2h') do
  # whatever code you want to run in 2 hours
end
```

The [github page](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) has tons of more examples.